# Waiting for events with a promise

Tags: node.js, events, socket.io, promise, bluebird

I would love to wrap an event in a promise.

More specifically I'd love to have an a way to have a promise that returns the values from every emitted event.

```
var events = require('events')
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter()

eventEmitter.on("add", function(data){
  console.log(data+1)
  return data+1
})

eventEmitter.emit('add', 5)
eventEmitter.emit('add', 3)

setTimeout(function(){
  eventEmitter.emit('add', 13)
}, 1000)

setTimeout(function(){
  eventEmitter.emit('add', 10)
}, 3000)
```

Here's a event that will emit `6, 4, 14, 11`. What I'd love is a promise wrapper that returns `[6, 4, 14, 11]`.

```
//eventWrapper(emissions, event, [eventArguments])

eventWrapper(4, eventEmitter, "add").then(console.log) // [6, 4, 14, 11]
```

Ideally there's a timeout argument as well so if an emission doesn't return and meet the emissions within `x` amount of seconds there's an error.

Finally (I know this is reaching a bit), but when it comes to socket.io there's an issue where upon the broadcasted emisson `.on` handlers won't return a callback, in this very specialized use, the event could be proxied to be handled by a totally different event, like this.

```
eventEmitter.on("callback", function(data){
  console.log(data+1)
  return data+1
})

eventEmitter.on("add", function(data){
  eventEmitter.emit("callback", data)
})
```

Instead of watching the original event for the callback, I'd need a way to pass in a second event, and proxy the callback to that event.

Ideally the function looked like this.

```
//eventWrapper(numberOfExpectedReturnedEvents, delimiterTimeoutIntervalBetweenEvents, eventAndParameters, proxyEventAndParameters)
eventWrapper(numberOfSockets, 5000, [socket.on, "action"], [socket.io, "callback"])
```

Comment: Promises only resolve or reject **once**. That's what they promise. Promises **cannot** replace event emitters. What can replace event emitters, if you're interested, are observables, in the functional reactive programming world. An example of a library using that is [bacon.js](https://baconjs.github.io/).

Comment: Thanks @FlorianMargaine I'm playing around with bacon.js, but I really don't get it. There aren't many examples with node, and even less with socket.io.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Florian said: **A Promise is not an event emitter**.

A promise represents a single value + time. However, in your code you're trying to represent an event which gets called multiple times.

If a promise is taking a single value and adding a time element to it. You're trying to take multiple values (an iteration of values) and add time to it. This is called an Observable and not a promise. A promise is not a good model for your problem.

Here is an example using RxJS since observables are not in EcmaScript yet ([but they're on their way](https://github.com/jhusain/asyncgenerator)):

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var emitter = new EventEmitter();

// an observable is what you use for multiple events
// fromEvent is the `promisify` of observables, you can also create them
// from sources - analogous to the promise constructor 
var observable = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(emitter, 'add');

// scanning a value and mappingthe result is done by `.scan`
// note how the syntax is similar to promise
// chaining - observables are functional and chain like promises
// observables also consume promises and can produce promises 
observable = observable.map(function(val){
    return val + 1;
});

// subscribe is like .done
observable.subscribe(console.log);
```